# How can I achieve collapsing toolbar with tab layout in react native

Tags: react-native, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How can I achieve  collapsing toolbar with tab layout in react native,

like 
   -- [image: Valid XHTML]

Suggest me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, achieved using react-native-scrollable-tabview

Comment: how to you achieve using `react-native-scrollable-tabview`?

Comment: @cwfei created a library using scrollable tabview,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-collapsing-tab-bar

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-collapsing-tab-bar
library to achieve collapsing toolbar

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to giving a parallax effect . The core logic behind implementing this is rendering a header . 
Checkout this [link](https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e) for detailed implementation

Comment: Hi @Abhinandan Sahgal ,
couldn't achieve with tab bar, using react-native-tab-bar